# Java version switcher in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have written a command-line tool to switch between different java versions, and as this is my first larger PowerShell script, I would like to get some feedback on the code.

The powershell file expects to find a list of directories containing JDKs in the directory of the script, lists them, and prompts the user to choose one.

`Jdk.ps1m`

```
class Jdk {
    [string] $Name
    [string] $Implementor
    [string] $Version
    
    Jdk(
        [string] $Name,
        [string] $Implementor,
        [string] $Version
    ) {
        $this.Name = $Name
        $this.Implementor = $Implementor
        $this.Version = $Version
    }
    
    static [Jdk] FromPath([IO.DirectoryInfo] $Path) {
        $Content = Join-Path $Path 'release' | Get-Item | Get-Content
        if ($Content -eq $null) {
            "Path {0} has no release file!" -f $Path | Write-Warning
            return $null
        }
        
        $Properties = [Jdk]::ParseReleaseFile($Content)
        
        return [Jdk]::new($Path, $Properties["IMPLEMENTOR"], $Properties["JAVA_VERSION"])
    }
    
    static [Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, string]] ParseReleaseFile([string[]] $Content) {
        [Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, string]] $Values = @{}
        foreach ($Line in $Content) {
            $Parts = $Line -split "="
            
            if ($Parts.length -ne 2) { continue; }
            
            $Key = $Parts[0]
            $Value = $Parts[1]
            
            if ($Value -NotMatch '^"([^"]|(\\"))*"$') { continue; }
            
            $Values[$Key] = $Value.SubString(1, $Value.length - 2)
        }
        return $Values
    }
}
```

`java-switcher.ps1`

```
Using module .\Jdk.psm1

$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path | Push-Location

Write-Output "Looking for JDKs in subfolders..."

$Jdks = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory |
    ? LinkType -eq $null |
    % {[Jdk]::FromPath($_)} |
    ? {$_ -ne $null}

Pop-Location

if ($Jdks.count -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "No JDKs found!"
    Exit 1
}

$Jdks |
    % {$index=0} {$_; $index++} |
    Format-Table -Property @{ Label="index";Expression={$index}; }, Name, Implementor, Version

[int] $Selected = Read-Host "Select index"
if ($Selected -lt 0 -or $Selected -gt $Jdks.length-1) {
    Write-Output "Invalid index!"
    Exit 1
}

Remove-Item "javapath" -Force -Recurse

& cmd.exe /c mklink /d javapath $Jdks[$Selected].Name
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
    & java --version
    Exit 0
}

& cmd.exe /c elevate mklink /d javapath $Jdks[$Selected].Name
& java --version
Exit $LASTEXITCODE
```